# .gitignore ignore folder, except subfolder

Tags: git, gitignore

I have to ignore the temp folder, excluding the bin subfolder. Also I shouldn't ignore some.txt in temp

My version of .gitignore file

```
temp/*
!temp/some.txt
!temp/bin
```

But I don't understand what is the difference between the first version (which I think is correct) and the two examples below? I'll be grateful for your explanation.

```
temp/*
!temp/some.txt
!temp/bin/

temp/*
!temp/some.txt
!temp/bin/*
```

Comment: These are globs. [According to the glob tester I use](https://globster.xyz/), if the path has a trailing `/`, it matches only directories and subdirectories.

Comment: @evolutionxbox  did I understand correctly that the first version is suitable for purpose?

Comment: I think `!temp/bin` will match files with the name `bin`.

Answer (score 1):

these two examples are identical

```bash
temp/*  // all files in temp folder
!temp/some.txt  // not some.txt in temp
!temp/bin/ // not all files or subdirectories in temp/bin

temp/*  // all files in temp folder
!temp/some.txt // not some.txt in temp
!temp/bin/* // no all files or subdirectories in bin folder
```

the main difference is from your first example

```bash
temp/*  // all files in temp folder
!temp/some.txt  // not some.txt in temp
!temp/bin  // not a file with the word beginning with `bin`
```